# Is "laughable" a noun or adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech, definition

My English professor corrected me when I wrote the following sentence: "What's so laughable?". Obviously I wanted to convey that something seemed laughable and I wanted to know what, but he answered that "laughable" is a noun, and he gave me this option: "What's something that you can laugh at?" I'm totally bewildered because in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary it appears only as and adjective. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "What's something you can laugh at?"  Something *laughable*, not "a laughable".    Is your professor a native speaker?

Comment: Hi, Andrew. Did you write "What's something you can laugh at?" because you considered that this question is better than "What's laughable?". No, he's not a native speaker but he teaches me in an institution here, in Mexico. Maybe he was just distracted or he misunderstood me.

Comment: I was just answering the question in a way that makes it clear "laughable" is an adjective.

Comment: You are right, and I guess why your professor got confused. There are English words with the suffix -able which can be adjectives and nouns, e.g.:  deliverable - "something that can be provided or achieved as a result of a process" (noun); "able to be delivered" (adjective).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your English professor is wrong, and you are right: *laughable* is an adjective. It might be employed as a noun (though I have never seen this), but if someone wrote or spoke of *the laughable* it would not designate a laughable entity (person, thing, event) but the category or set of all entities which are laughable.

I think, too, that your English professor misunderstands your question "What's so laughable?" If you are employing this in its ordinary, entirely idiomatic sense you are not, as your professor's paraphrase suggests, asking your hearer to name some laughable entity—you are asking your hearer to justify the characterization of a particular entity as *laughable*.